# Algotrading: How to incorporate this type of trailing stop?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, forex

I currently have a system that opens a trade almost every 5 minutes.

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around creating a trailing stop loss that does something like this:

scan all open orders every tick and modify them, if they have not been modified already, like this:

1. start with static stoploss of 25 pips
2. at 5 pips profit move stoploss to entry price
3. at 8 pips profit move stoploss 4 pips behind 8 pips profit (current price)

This is what I have so far

```
//---- input parameters
extern double     InitialStop     = 25;
extern double     BreakEven       = 20;    // Profit Lock in pips  
extern double     StepSize        =  5;
extern double     MinDistance     = 10;

int   k, digit=0;
bool BE = false;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
  {

//----
   return(0);
  }

// ---- Stepped Stops
void StepStops()
{        
    double BuyStop, SellStop;
    int total=OrdersTotal();
    for (int cnt=0;cnt<total;cnt++)
    { 
     OrderSelect(cnt, SELECT_BY_POS);   
     int mode=OrderType();    
        if ( OrderSymbol()==Symbol() ) 
        {
            if ( mode==OP_BUY )
            {
               BuyStop = OrderStopLoss();
               if ( Bid-OrderOpenPrice()>0 || OrderStopLoss()==0) 
               {
               if ( Bid-OrderOpenPrice()>=Point*BreakEven && !BE) {BuyStop = OrderOpenPrice();BE = true;}

               if (OrderStopLoss()==0) {BuyStop = OrderOpenPrice() - InitialStop * Point; k=1; BE = false;}

               if ( Bid-OrderOpenPrice()>= k*StepSize*Point) 
               {
               BuyStop = OrderStopLoss()+ StepSize*Point; 
               if (Bid - BuyStop >= MinDistance*Point)
               { BuyStop = BuyStop; k=k+1;}
               else
               BuyStop = OrderStopLoss();
               }                              
               //Print( " k=",k ," del=", k*StepSize*Point, " BuyStop=", BuyStop," digit=", digit);
               OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),
                           NormalizeDouble(BuyStop, digit),
                           OrderTakeProfit(),0,LightGreen);
                  return(0);
                  }
               }
            if ( mode==OP_SELL )
            {
               SellStop = OrderStopLoss();
               if ( OrderOpenPrice()-Ask>0 || OrderStopLoss()==0) 
               {
               if ( OrderOpenPrice()-Ask>=Point*BreakEven && !BE) {SellStop = OrderOpenPrice(); BE = true;}

               if ( OrderStopLoss()==0 ) { SellStop = OrderOpenPrice() + InitialStop * Point; k=1; BE = false;}

               if ( OrderOpenPrice()-Ask>=k*StepSize*Point) 
               {
               SellStop = OrderStopLoss() - StepSize*Point; 
               if (SellStop - Ask >= MinDistance*Point)
               { SellStop = SellStop; k=k+1;}
               else
               SellStop = OrderStopLoss();
               }
               //Print( " k=",k," del=", k*StepSize*Point, " SellStop=",SellStop," digit=", digit);
               OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),
                          NormalizeDouble(SellStop, digit),
                          OrderTakeProfit(),0,Yellow);      
               return(0);
               }    
            }
         }   
      } 
}

// ---- Scan Trades
int ScanTrades()
{   
   int total = OrdersTotal();
   int numords = 0;

   for(int cnt=0; cnt<total; cnt++) 
   {        
   OrderSelect(cnt, SELECT_BY_POS);            
   if(OrderSymbol() == Symbol() && OrderType()<=OP_SELL) 
   numords++;
   }
   return(numords);
}


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
  {
//---- 

//----
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| expert start function                                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
{
   digit  = MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_DIGITS);


   if (ScanTrades()<1) return(0);
   else
   if (BreakEven>0 || InitialStop>0 || StepSize>0) StepStops(); 

 return(0);
}//int start
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, this EA does start with a static stop loss of 25 pips but I couldnt get it to do the last two steps which are:

2. at 5 pips profit move stoploss to entry price
3. at 8 pips profit move stoploss 4 pips behind 8 pips profit (current price)

Would really help a ton if you can share code/ideas that I can incorporate into my EA or run as a standalone script/EA.

Thank you

Comment: use `class CDeal : public Object` and `CArrayObj` to keep them all (alternatively arrays) and keep status of each trade you have. Status will tell you what movement a trade has already passed and what is the next scenario for each trade. in such a case if a trade was 8 pips in profit and you moved sl to 4pips, you wont move back sl to breakeven after price goes +5 pips. Share your attempts with MCVE to get help

Comment: Could you give me an example, in code?

Comment: sure. show what you have, an MCVE and we will start from it. There is no coders here who will code for you

Comment: I truly appreciate it, Ill edit my post with the relevant updated code in MQL4 language. Thank you again

Comment: Make sure to check that `OrderModify()` does not return an error code, and if it does, print it to the *Experts* console. Since you are using very narrow pips, it is possible that you are not using the minimum required for changing/placing an order. `SymbolInfoInteger(Symbol(),SYMBOL_TRADE_STOPS_LEVEL);` and `MarketInfo(Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL);`

Comment: if you found the solution please share

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not apply the SL on the server side, and you close the position by your own code directly whenever the condition is satisfied.